# how to copy top 100 files of a particular extension to a target folder using terminal

Tags: shell

I would like to copy the top 1000 files of a particular extension to a target folder using my terminal, but everytime I run the command

```
cp `ls -1 11944*.DAT|tail -n 1000` /ftp/BSEG_SRC
```

it shows error like /ftp/BSEG_SRC is a directory , Argument list too long.
Could you kindly help me here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument list being too long happens because when you do this:

```
ls -1 11944*.DAT
```

It tries to construct a huge line like:

```
foo bar [...] baz quux
```

And there is of course a limit on how long a command line can be.  The good news is that it's easy to fix--just use `find` to match the files you want, then `xargs` to launch `cp`, because `xargs` knows how long the maximum length of a single command is, and will launch `cp` several times as required:

```
find -name '11944*.DAT' | tail -n 1000 | xargs -I{} cp {} /ftp/BSEG_SRC
```

By the way, there is no specified sort order here, because your original question didn't have any.